# Method not found Error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am new to node.js and mongo db. What I am trying to do is to call the ordered function in my model.js from index.js but I have a complain

> object function model() has no method ordered()

routes/index.js

```
var pics_ = models.Picture.ordered();
```

model.js

```
Picture.prototype.ordered = function() {
var ordered = mongoose.Picture.find().sort({points:-1}).toArray()
console.log(ordered);
return ordered;
};
```

Comment: Are you exporting Picture object in model.js?

Comment: yes. I am var 
Picture = mongoose.model('Picture', PictureSchema);
exports.Picture = Picture;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add methods to your models, you should use the Mongoose supported ways for doing that.  See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/methods-statics.html